# jQuery - Why pre-pending a sliced anchor tag doesn't work

Tags: jquery, string, slice, prepend

I have an element whose HTML I am restricting to max character count, then I'm adding a "Read more" link, which is used to expand hidden content.

The element's content contains dynamic HTML that needs sliced; mainly`<p>`, `<ul>/<ol>`, and `<a>` tags.

The first solution I tried seemed to fail when the max character count fell upon an `<a>` tag:

```
var $element = $(".element");
var elementHTML = $element.html();
var maxCharCount = 250;

$element.prepend("<div class='new-preview-text'>"+
    elementHTML.slice(0, maxCharCount) + 
    "...<br>" +
    "<a class='introtext-collapse-link introtext-see-more'><span class='collapse-arrow collapse-arrow-down'></span>Read More</a>"+
    "</div>"
    );
```

This worked fine when the maxCharCount sliced inside a `<p>` or `<ul>/<ol>`, **but when slicing an `<a>` tag, only the div.new-preview-text was prepended; the break tag and new "Read more" link were left out.**

Prepending only the div element, then appending the break tag/new Read more link worked:

```
$element.prepend("<div class='new-preview-text'>"+
    elementHTML.slice(0, maxCharCount));

$element.find(".new-preview-text").children().last().append("...<br>");
$element.find(".new-preview-text").append("<a class='introtext-collapse-link introtext-see-more'><span class='collapse-arrow collapse-
    arrow-down'></span>Read more</a>");
```

but I don't understand why. Can anyone see the error in the first solution?

Comment: Well... if you slice off the end of an a tag, you'd lose it's closing `</a>` no?  Or am i misunderstanding you.

Comment: At first I thought this was the issue as well, but when a `<p>` or `<ul>/<ol>` were sliced into (if maxCharCount fell in the center), then the closing tag, `</p>`,`</ul>`, `</ol>` was added after the new Read more link and before the closing div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jgbj5suo/  Yeah, I'm assuming the issue is because the closing </a> is being lost.  So the browser parser is having to guess where it should close the tag.  If you inspect the result it closes the link before the start of the next link.

Comment: Nice, well this seems like the obvious reason then! Do you want to add your last comment as the answer?

Comment: Nah, I just pointed out the issue.  Not a solution for it, ^_~

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Taplar!